# SSIS Package to loop through a table for Stored Procedure names and execute them

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a table with all the stored procedure names saved into one column. I am currently fetching these names as a "Result Set" into an object variable `strProcs` using "*Execute SQL Task*".

I need to loop through all these stored procedure names and execute them in the same order. How can I achieve this using a ForEach Loop Container or another elegant solution? Thank you for your help.

Comment: do those procedures need additional input or output parameters?

Comment: If you need them to execute in order, you'll need to add a column like `SortOrder`, and use that value in your iterator. The table itself is, by definition, an unordered set and your query to retrieve the data isn't guaranteed to bring the list back in any particular order on any particular run through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a string variable, let's say `ProcName`. This will hold the stored proc name as we iterate through the loop.

Next, create a Foreach Loop, set the Enumerator to `Foreach ADO Enumerator`, set your source variable to `User::strProcs` object variable. Then under `Variable Mappings` in the left pane, add a new entry, selecting `User::ProcName` and setting the index to 0 (assuming the proc name is the first column of `strProcs`).

Then, add an `Execute SQL Task` inside the loop container. Configure the connection to your db, and then set `SQLSourceType` to `Direct input`. For the `SQLStatement`, you're going to build a simple dynamic query using your ProcName variable. It will looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(128) = ?
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC ' + @ProcName

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Hit `OK` to save the query, and then go to `Parameter Mapping` in the left pane. Add an entry, setting the variable name to `User::ProcName`, direction to `Input`, data type to 
 `VARCHAR`, parameter name to 0, and parameter size to 128. Hit `OK` to save the `Execute SQL Task` configuration.

And that's it! Note that this is a simplified explanation for procs that contain no parameters. If you needed to pass parameters, you would have to add them into the value that gets assigned to the @query variable so they get executed with the rest of the dynamic sql.

EDIT:

Ravi asked: "I am going to run the queries in an order (around 200 stored procedures) and I do have an "ID Number" field in the table. Is there any possibility for me to update the start time, execute the procedure and update the end time back to the database?"

I'm going to presume you have a table in your db that has the ID, proc name, LastStartTime, and LastEndTime. And I'm also going to presume that your ADO record set in SSIS has the ID value and the proc name, and let's say that the columns are in that order, too.

Working with what you created above, you could follow these steps to modify a few tasks and have your expanded solution.

First, create an Int32 variable, let's call it `ProcID`. Next, we'll modify the Foreach Loop configuration so that ID gets loaded into ProcID. Right click on the Loop container and choose `Edit`. Click on `Variable Mappings` in the left pane and add `User::ProcID` under Variable and set the Index to 0. Set the Index of `User::ProcName` to 1. Hit `OK` to save the changes to the Loop.

Next, you'll modify the `Execute SQL Task` that executes the dynamic SQL. So open up that configuration editor, and update the `SQLStatement` so that it looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(128) = ?
DECLARE @ProcID INT = ?
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC ' + @ProcName

UPDATE ProcTable
SET LastStartTime = GETDATE()
WHERE ID = @ProcID

EXECUTE(@query)

UPDATE ProcTable
SET LastEndTime = GETDATE()
WHERE ID = @ProcID
```

You can `UPDATE` the table before the proc call and then again after the proc call. You don't need a Script Task here.

We're also mapping another variable into our SQL script, so after you edit the `SQLStatement`, click on `Parameter Mapping` in the left pane, hit the `Add` button, and choose `User::ProcID` as the Variable Name, data type can stay as `LONG`, set Parameter Name to 1, and Parameter Size to -1. Hit OK.

And then you're done and ready to test.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This is excellent. I am not aware of how to create a dynamic SQL query. Helped me a lot. As Eric mentioned, I am going to run the queries in an order (around 200 stored procedures) and I do have an "ID Number" field in the table.

Is there any possibility for me to update the start time, execute the procedure and update the end time back to the database? From a novice perspective, it seems like "Script Task" is the only way to go :). Can you help me extending this part as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that, and you don't need a Script Task to do it. You can expand your Execute SQL Task to do the `UPDATE`s, as I explain in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Worked perfectly for me. I got this done in a different way. But this is more elegant :). Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, if you learned two new ways to do something, I'd say that's a win!